# Limit supported methods to type of generic parameter in Swift 4

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

Given a struct of some generic type, I want to limit which methods may be called to only those which are subtypes of the generic type.

```
struct ViewBuilder<T:UIView> {

    let parent:UIView

    func createView() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        parent.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}

extension ViewBuilder where T:UIButton {

    func createButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        parent.addSubview(button)
        return button
    }
}
```

In this code I specify the **builder should only create `UIControls`**:

```
let builder = ViewBuilder<UIControl>(parent:UIView())
let view = builder.createView() // ok
let button = builder.createButton() //  'UIControl' is not a subtype of 'UIButton'
```

However, as you can see, I get the opposite behavior; a `UIView` is *not* a `UIControl`; a `UIButton` *is* a `UIControl`. Any way to do this in Swift? (I'm using Swift 4.) I've tried several things using generics and protocols but no luck.

(I understand *why* the above code works the way it does, but I'm looking for alternative the overall problem if one exists. If anyone can propose a good solution perhaps I can improve the question to fit.)

Comment: I'm lost as to what you're trying to do here. Nothing in your code above says "should only create `UIControl`." What part did you mean? `createView`? `createButton`?

Comment: This is a very dumbed down version of the original code. I mainly would like to know if it's possible to create a builder that limits the API based on a provided type. In this example the type is passed to the ViewBuilder by generic parameter. One thing I've tried is constraining a type on the method to be a subtype of the builder generic type, like `func button<V:UIButton>() -> V where V:T` but that doesn't compile because Swift doesn't support it: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#user-content-conditional-conformances-via-protocol-extensions

Comment: You can't limit the API, but I assume you mean only expand the API based on the type. If you want `createButton` to be available when `T:UIControl`, then you should just add `where T:UIControl`. But you're creating a `ViewBuilder` of `UIControl`, and then trying to make a button (without adding `createButton` for `UIControl`). It feels like just writing down what you want will exactly do the thing you want here, so I'm confused where the trouble is.

Comment: I understand the confusion. I spent all day confused about this! :p Fact is, I really _do_ want to limit the API to only be subtypes of the provided type, so that for example if the constraint is `UIControl` then `createView()` would _not_ be available (because a view is not a control). Adding the `where T:UIControl` to either the extension or the `createButton` method yields the same error in my description.

Comment: To clarify: adding `where T:UIControl` to either the extension or `createButton` avoids the error on `createButton`, but does not provide what I really want: to have an error on `createView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to remove a method from a subtype (`T where T:...` is a subtype of `T`). That's a fundamental feature of types. A subtype must be able to do everything a type can do. Otherwise, if a function took a generic `ViewBuilder<T>`, how would it know whether `createView` were allowed on it or not? Extensions are *extensions*. They may not even be visible to consumers of the type.

In principle, this is what you're really asking for:

```
struct ViewBuilder<T: UIView> {

    let parent: UIView

    func create<U:T>() -> U {
        let view = U()
        parent.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}
```

This provides a `create` method for any type that is a subtype of `T`, which must itself be a subtype of `UIView`. Unfortunately, this is not currently legal Swift ([SR-5213](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5213)). The problem is that a generic type parameter that is constrained by a class is not itself considered a class for the purpose of constraining additional type parameters.

Given this limitation, in most cases I would probably use composition like this:

```
struct ViewBuilder {
    let parent: UIView

    func create<View: UIView>(_ type: View.Type) -> View {
        let view = View()
        parent.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }
}

struct ControlBuilder {
    private let builder: ViewBuilder
    var parent: UIView { return builder.parent }

    init(parent: UIView) {
        builder = BaseViewBuilder(parent: parent)
    }

    func create<Control: UIControl>(_ type: Control.Type) -> Control {
        return builder.create(type)
    }
}

let builder = ControlBuilder(parent:UIView())
let button = builder.create(UIButton.self)
```

Here a `ControlBuilder` HASA `ViewBuilder` rather than ISA `ViewBuilder`. This has some limitations if you want to accept "something that can create a kind of view" since it's pretty much impossible (as far as I can tell) to create a protocol that covers both of these because of SR-5213. But given your examples, this looks like it would match your use case.

(I'm kind of suspicious of this entire use case, though. I'm unclear how "a view that can only contain controls" is useful. It feels like what you really want are extensions on `UIView`. "Builder" feel like an attempt to import Java patterns into Swift that may not fit.)

Comment: Thanks Rob for pointing out the limitation in Swift and taking the time to provide an alternate solution. Composition wins again! :) As for the use-case, I agree. Turns out _not_ to be the best fit for my API at the moment, but I'll keep the pattern in mind should it arise again.